# Rancher imageUuid not Unique

Tags: docker, rancher

While adding a service i forgot to add a part in the url, should be xxx/yyy/zzz but input xxx/zzz.

After stopping the stack and trying to correct the error i get the following error:

> Validation failed in API: imageUuid

I've tried removing all stacks and reinserting the service. It however won't add it again and i've found no way to remove it from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Think this is a bug, i'm using a private repository, so the address is:

> private.dns.name:8080/project/tools/toola

This is not supported by Rancher, the following does work:

> private.dns.name:8080/tools/toola

Comment: Seems you have reported it to Rancher Labs as https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/3122